# JMenuBar won't show up in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenu, jmenubar

I know this question has been asked a lot but nothing seems to be working for me so I'll ask again. I'm trying to get a JMenuBar, with a JMenu, to show up in my Window class which extends JFrame. Here is my relevant code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
    //class variables
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu;

    Window() throws IOExcpetion {

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    this.add(menuBar); //I've tried with and without this
    menu.setVisible(true);
    menuBar.setVisible(true);

    this.setVisible(true);

    while(true) {
        repaint(); //my paint method doesn't touch the JMenuBar or JMenu
    }
}
```

Comment: `"//my paint method doesn't touch the JMenuBar or JMenu"` -- but it "touches" and freezes the Swing event thread (as per Mad's answer -- 1+ to it!).

Answer (score 2):

Kill...

```
while(true) {
    repaint(); //my paint method doesn't touch the JMenuBar or JMenu
}
```

This is blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, making it impossible for the system to paint, well, anything...

Also...

```
menu.setVisible(true);
menuBar.setVisible(true);
```

Swing components are visible by default, so the above is pointless, I know, you were scratching at crumbs, but you should beware that this is very rarely the problem

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestWindow extends JFrame {

    //class variables
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu;

    TestWindow() throws IOException {

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
//        this.add(menuBar); //I've tried with and without this
//        menu.setVisible(true);
//        menuBar.setVisible(true);

        this.setVisible(true);

//        while (true) {
//            repaint(); //my paint method doesn't touch the JMenuBar or JMenu
//        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }

                    TestWindow frame = new TestWindow();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, to restate, repaint() kills the swing thread? And your code above deals with this by creating a runnable in a different thread? I need to call paint to constantly update the screen (this is a moving game, and the screen is constantly updated). How can I keep the menubar up top while updating the screen? I tried moving my JMenuBar code into my paint method but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: No, the loop kills the Event Dispatching Thread.  You can't block the EDT, this will prevent it from processing the event queue, which is where repaint requests are schedule, amongst all the other user related events, like mouse and keyboard events and a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: My code ensures that the UI is created within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, Swing (like most UI frameworks) is single threaded environment and is NOT thread safe.  This means that you MUST only update UI elements from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: If you need to perform periodical updates to the screen, then you need to use something like `javax.swing.Timer`, which will allow you to setup a periodical callback (to an `ActionListener`) which will be called from within the context of the EDT, making it suitable to use to update the state of the UI safely

Comment: You need to have a better idea of concurrency in general, but especially with how it relates to the Swing framework, take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details